# Is circular referencing required in this situation?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript

```
class ItemList {  
   constructor() {
     this.list = [];//list holds many instances of Item Class
   }
   
   removeItem(id) {
   //...search for item in this.list, remove it
   }
}

class Item {   
    constructor(parent) {
    this.id = 123456;
    this.parent = parent;//ItemList
    }

    removeSelf() {
        this.parent.removeItem(this.id);
    }
}
```

The item class is able to delete itself and the state of ItemList is updated.

Is circular referencing required?

What design pattern(s) can address this?

Comment: This strategy doesn't scale in the sense that: what if one item is in multiple lists? Logically, removal from the list is the responsibility of the list holder, the authoritative source for the list.  Alternately, we could make the "`parent`" another list..

Comment: _"It's important that the item class is able to delete itself"_ I'm with Erik here (comment above) and am going to put a very big question mark on that. Speaking from experience, I don't think this is important at all, it's just how you currently are thinking of approaching the problem at hand. This is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You're asking about how to achieve X, when in reality you're doing X because you want to achieve Y, and you should be asking us how to achieve Y. I'm commenting this because learning about (and spotting) XY problems is important.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coming to the conclusion that the very way I'm approaching this is just wrong. Thank you for comments.

As for additional context, I basically have a UI list and I want each item on this list to be able to delete itself. I'm thinking of making an event listener on the parent and just tieing the listener to the child's "delete" event.

Thank you for mentioning XY problems, I've never heard of them before but I'll definitely dig into it.

Comment: I actually don't think there's anything inherently wrong with the bidirectional reference. It just depends what you're modeling. You're in UI territory, in particular. The DOM, which has node properties that access and depend on the parent node, is a reasonable model to follow.

Comment: "Item has pointer to parent": very common pattern. Item having methods which just forward to parent: less common and more of a code smell. Just expose getParent() and let the caller do it

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you seem to have changed your mind there is a solution to this problem and its 'events'

we have to be a bit careful in javascript because 'events' and 'event handling' in javascript normally refer to DOM events like button.onClick() But here we want to add events to our own objects.

We can use a pub sub pattern to make the framework which I won't attempt to detail here but look at this example : https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js

Then you have your list and item classes

```
class ItemList {  
   constructor() {
     this.list = [];//list holds many instances of Item Class
     pubSub.ListenFor('RemoveItem', this.removeItem);
   }
   addItem(item) {
      this.list.add(item)
   }
   removeItem(id) {
   //...search for item in this.list, remove it
   }
}



class Item {   
    constructor() {
    this.id = 123456;
    }

    RemoveFromLists() {
        pubSub.Publish('RemoveItem', this.Id);
    }
}
```

Now, when RemoveFromLists is called, the item will be removed from any lists its been added to.

Really you want only to call listeners on lists where it's actually been added, which you can do with a more complex pub sub pattern, or by passing the id around more.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making your data structure more complicated than it needs to be by adhering to a class based approach in the spirit of doing things object oriented.

A more logical way would be using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It already has all the required operations built-in:

```js
const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] // Items
items.push({id: 4}) // Add item
items.splice(items.findIndex(item => item.id === 2), 1) // Remove item by id
```

Alternatively, without mutating the original array:

```js
let items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] // Items
items = items.concat({id: 4}) // Add item
items = items.filter(item => item.id !== 2) // Remove item by id
```